ignoring files for prettier doesn't work I tried placing it in many different directories
I am trying to ignore one specific file from prettier because it messes up the format but it is not working.
First I put a .prettierignore file in the directory the file is in and added * to the ignore file - Doesn't work
Then I put the ignore file in the root of the project with a path to the file I want to ignore in the inside the ignore file - Also doesn't work
Do I have to restart VS code after adding the ignore file?
So how do I ignore one specific file from prettier please?
this is my file structure
back/static/js/filetoignore.js
.prettierignore is in the same folder as back

The .prettierignore file should be placed at the root of your project. You can ignore that file by including it with its relative path from there:
/static/js/filetoignore.js

